# Auto-logout of session after x seconds for a user type (Yii 1.x)

Tags: php, session, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I have a Yii 1.x application that uses the WebUser component for a login section of the website - within my config/main.php I have the following block within my components section that will automatically timeout the session after 2 hours (e.g 3600 x 2 or 7200 seconds).

This works fine in the sense that a user is 'kicked out' of my application after the set number of seconds - but how would I amend this to have this log out certain 'types' of user with different expirations.

e.g If user type == 1 then logout after 3600 seconds, if user type == 2 then logout after 7200 seconds...

```
// config/main.php
'components'        => array(
   'user'    => array(
       'class'   => 'application.components.WebUser',
       'allowAutoLogin' => true,
       'loginUrl'           => array('frontend/user/login'),
       'loginRequiredAjaxResponse' => 'CR_SESSION_EXPIRED',
       'authTimeout'       => 3600*2, // auto-logout after 2 hours
        ),
 .......
```

Note - this is using Yii 1.x rather than Yii 2.0.

I am presuming this would need to be within the WebUser integration rather than the config file..

-- update --
I've added the following block to the WebUser.php component (that extends CWebUser)

```
    public function init() {
    parent::init();

    if (($user = $this->getState('userModel')) !== null) {

        $this->authTimeout = 5;
        $this->absoluteAuthTimeout = 5;
        $this->setUserData(unserialize($user));
    }
}
```

I've set the authTimeout & absoluteAuthTimout to 5 seconds but I still remain logged in after 5 seconds... any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just set the `$authTimeout` property by overwriting the `init()` function of your `WebUser` class? You can base that on values stored in your config. There shouldn't be any logic in your config file, just values.

Comment: You should call `parent::init();` after your logic. It now sets the session first and sets your new `$authTimeout` after.

Comment: Think i sussed it!! Thanks - the prev dev made a number of changes to the WebUser that it was doing something quite different to the original CWebUser.. eg it was never calling the updateAuthStatus for one...

Comment: @JelledeFries Awesome... this is all making sense now :-) its been one of them days! Thanks for your efforts.. it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment.

I think you should be able to overwrite the value in your `WebUser` class.

```
<?php
class WebUser extends CWebUser{

    public $authTimeouts = array(); //array with the timeouts

    public function init(){
        //you need to get the userType first
        if(array_key_exists($userType,$this->authTimeouts)){ 
            $authTimeout = $this->authTimeouts[$userType];
        }
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Then your config should look like this:

```
// config/main.php
'components'        => array(
   'user'    => array(
       'class'   => 'application.components.WebUser',
       'allowAutoLogin' => true,
       'loginUrl'           => array('frontend/user/login'),
       'loginRequiredAjaxResponse' => 'CR_SESSION_EXPIRED',
       'authTimeout'       => 3600*2, // auto-logout after 2 hours
       'authTimeouts'=> array(
            'userType1' => 10,
            'userType2' => 500,
            ),
        ),
 ......
```

Something like that.
For more info on the source code and the `init()` function see:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L196

Comment: i've overwritten these values to no avail... am i doing something wrong in a config file?